# 404 Error NoSuchBucket using website endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am attempting to complete the cloud resume challenge. When I click the website endpoint link for my s3 bucket it get this

> 404 Not Found
> Code: NoSuchBucket
> Message: The specified bucket does not exist
> BucketName: [www.travissalmon.com](http://www.travissalmon.com)
> RequestId: 5Q1DS4WWERWHTYK8
> HostId: InN2VG08C3F/TV7mFdFtaiM/tpamg6NpCWRk46SSAc+gI9yUW3oM0tK0ebl3+E4vCZP/6DSoNCM=

My bucket name is "travissalmon.com" not "www.travissalmon.com"

I already have my bucket Public Accessible

My bucket policy is this

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "MyPolicy",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicGetObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::travissalmon.com/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

I am not sure how to resolve this issue. I've seen people mention the naming convention for S3 on other post but I believe I followed it correctly.

I already have my custom DNS being "travissalmon.com".

I saw in a video it should match the name of the S3 bucket you wish to point it to when hosting a static website

I also have static website hosting enabled

Although when I paste the link into an incognito window on google chrome, the website endpoint link works